# Access methods defined in another groovy script

Tags: groovy, import

I have two groovy scripts `A` and `B`.

`A` looks like:

```
import some.Class

//Some helper function
String doSomeWork(Integer input) {
    //does something with input and returns a String
    return "result: $input"
}

//Now do some real stuff here
println( doSomeWork(42) )
```

In `B` I want to import `A` (its in the classpath) and use its `doSomeWork`:

<strike>import A
    println A //prints class A. This means we can access it here. =)
    println( A.doSomeWork(45) ) //Now try to call As doSomeWork</strike>

The last line however results in an exception:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static A.doSomeWork() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [45]
Possible solutions: doSomeWork(java.lang.Integer)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static A.doSomeWork() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [45]
Possible solutions: doSomeWork(java.lang.Integer)
    at B.run(B.groovy:3)
```

```
import A //Will execute As code
println A //prints class A. This means we can access it here. =)
println( (new A()).doSomeWork(45) ) //Now call As doSomeWork
```

<strike>What do I have to do to successfull call `A`s `doSomeWork` in script `B`?</strike>

EDIT: Okay, I found out. it is not a static method but a method of `A`. So (new A()).doSomeWork(45) is doing the job. However, that means when `A` is imported, all its code is executed before `B`s code. How can I avoid that? My goal is to only use `A`s method (which obvioulsy does not access any of `A`s properties) without `A` doing any other side effects.

Comment: "All its code is executed before `B`s code" means the `println( doSomeWork(42) )` plus the method in `A` I assume. But if that is right, then your solution already prevents the execution of that. If that is not what you mean, please clarify

Comment: In my opinion using Groovy in object mode (i.e. classA extends classB) not "two scripts" philosophy give cleaner presentation of problem, programmers idea, dependencies etc....